# Swift How to Display High Score

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to figure out how to save the high score and then display it on the GameOverScene. I have seen people use NSUserDefaults but I am not sure how to use them. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code that has to do with keeping score.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    scoreLabel.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width/2, view.frame.size.height/7/10)
    scoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    self.view?.addSubview(scoreLabel)
}

func heroDidCollideWithwall(hero:SKSpriteNode, wall:SKSpriteNode) {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.lose()

func heroDidCollideWithscorePlane(hero:SKSpriteNode, scorePlane: SKSpriteNode) {
    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.heroCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.wallCategory) != 0) {
    heroDidCollideWithwall(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, wall: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    } else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.heroCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.scoreCategory) != 0) {
        heroDidCollideWithscorePlane(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, scorePlane: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
```

Comment: Please try and follow this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-voOzp-bK8)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you store Score which is type integer or float; like a NSDictionary Key:Value

here is how you can store Score using NSUserDefaults,
For example you store "newHighScore" Value

```
var newHighScore = 12

var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(newHighScore, forKey: "YourKeyValue")
```

and how you access this score

```
let storedHighScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("YourKeyValue")
```

if you store float value then your code, not setInteger or when accessing integerForKey your code is setFloat And FloatForKey

For example access score second way and you compare newScore and stored score, which is bigger than another you stored that number the same keyValue and your high score updating